# Move files into folders based on part of their name, but without creating the folders first

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of folder like this

```
Il Piccolo Sceriffo
Marvel Mix 
Orfani 
Plutos
Oscar Bestsellers
Pecos Bill
```

and I have files like this

```
Il Piccolo Sceriffo 41 (Dardo 1994-03) [c2c dinofelix].cbr
Il piccolo sceriffo 44 (Dardo 1994-06) [c2c mystere e dinofelix].cbr
Marvel Mix 006 [1996-09][ITA][c2c][Cer8 - Miao Films].cbr
Orfani 042 - Terra 3 - Oltre il muro (2017-03).cbr
Oscar Bestsellers 1461 - Pippo Pensieri In Liberta' (Mondadori 2004-06).cbr
Pecos Bill 047 - Serie 3 - 10-11-12 (Dardo 1997-04) (c2c) [Ciupie - Dinofelix].cbr
```

To move files in their folder like this

```
Il Piccolo Sceriffo
|
|--- Il Piccolo Sceriffo 41 (Dardo 1994-03) [c2c dinofelix].cbr
|--- Il piccolo sceriffo 44 (Dardo 1994-06) [c2c mystere e dinofelix].cbr

Marvel Mix 
|
|--- Marvel Mix 006 [1996-09][ITA][c2c][Cer8 - Miao Films].cbr

Orfani 
|
|--- Orfani 042 - Terra 3 - Oltre il muro (2017-03).cbr
```

I use this script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:-d`) do (
    set "_file=%%a"
    for /D %%b in (*) do (
        if NOT "x!_file:%%b=!" == "x!_file!" (
            move "%%a" "%%b"
        )
    )
)
popd
```

**Question**: I need to create a folder list before if I want to move. But I don't want to create folders before. 
Is there a way to create folders to move their files according their name in the manner closest to the example I gave?

**EDIT**:  I created the folders before using the script. What I try is to create the new folders through the script, without having to manually create them first.

The patterns of my names are 4 : 
NAME *space +  numbers*
NAME space `-`
NAME SPACE NAME *space +  numbers*
NAME SPACE NAME *space +  `-`*

For example:

**Alan 02**
***Alan -***
**Alan Ford 09**
***Alan Ford -***

Comment: Unclear.. you want to move files to new folders, but do not want to create these folders??

Comment: No, I created the folders before using the script. What I try is to create the new folders through the script, without having to manually create them first.

Comment: If you've pre-created the directories, then perform the task backwards. Do a directory listing, get the names of those directories, and search for files which begin with those names. If found, move those files to the already existing directory. Example: `For /D %%G In (*) Do If Exist "%%G*.cbr" Move /Y "%%G*.cbr" "%%G"`; Or do it and ignore any error messages for directories which do not exist, e.g. `For /D %%G In (*) Do Move /Y "%%G*.cbr" "%%G" 2>NUL`.

Comment: @Compo eh .. but that's what I don't want to do, I don't want the script to work on pre-created folders (my script already does!), I would like it to create them by identifying in the file names the corresponding folder names that we need instead create and the reason to move those files.

Comment: If your issue is that you want to pre-create the directories within the script itself, then you'll need to formulate a pattern for splitting the filenames. It looks as if all you should need to do, based upon the names you've provided is split it at the space character(s) which precede the first numerical digit, _(or sequence of digits)_. I would doubt however, in a real world scenario, that you will never have intended directory names which do not themselves contain a string beginning with a numbers, and which you'd like to remain in the name.

Comment: yes, splitter could be a number [0-9] or the first special simbol as `-`. i think that number should be better but I have also some names like *Alan Ford - volume 1*, *Alan Ford - volume 2* etc so is useful consider first simbol also `-` and not only a sequence of digits

Comment: Unless you have a naming pattern which is consistent, then you cannot expect a script/scripter to be able to determine your intended directory names from poorly named files. You'll have to decide on one or the other, I'm certainly not going to guess the names of every one of your CBR files, and then put together a very complicated script to guess which of the resultant directory names will include isolated numbers, and which will not. _BTW, I see you used  the term `[0-9]` in your previous comment, please do not use that if you're thinking of using `findstr.exe`, use `[0123456789]` instead._

Comment: The patterns of my names are 4 : NAME *space +  numbers*, NAME space `-`, NAME SPACE NAME *space +  numbers* and NAME SPACE NAME *space +  `-`*.. For example: **Alan 02**, ***Alan -*** ,**Alan Ford 09**, ***Alan Ford -***

Comment: When you've decided upon your exact pattern(s), update your code to include your attempts at the task you require of it. This site does not write your code for you, we only help you to fix a single specific and reproducible issue with your own code. What you've currently submitted, performs not splitting of the filenames, uses no patterns, and makes no attempt at the task you've laid out in your question and subsequent comments. Incidentally, I've removed the [[tag:powershell]] tag and reference from your question. There is no powershell code in your post, _**this is not a request service**_.

Comment: yes, you're right, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on your defined pattern `some string with or without spaces` followed by `space` followed by a number or a `-`.
You can't split by spaces, as there may be one or more within in the first (wanted) string, but you can split at numbers and `-`. Just don't forget to remove the last char (a space) from the found string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.cbr) do (
  for /f "delims=0123456789-" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    set "folder=%%b"
    ECHO md "!folder:~0,-1!" 2>nul
    ECHO move "%%a" "!folder:~0,-1!\"
  )
)
```

I disarmed the `md` and `move` commands for security reasons. Remove the `ECHO`'s after troubleshooting.

NOTE: this has problems if the filename contains an exclamation mark.